# Filter in list by responseEentity in Java

Tags: java, primavera

I need to filter a list with a response

```
   ResponseEntity<Gruoup> listaGrupo = monstarListaGrupo(login, token);
List<Diretorio> diretorios = lista.stream()
        .filter(x-> x.getGrupoAd() == listaGrupo.getBody().getGrupos())
```

I tried to do it that way but he doesn't let it because it says that one type is list and another is String

Apartment filter of a RespondeEntity in an age list for exam

RespondeEntity:

```
    {
        "name": "barry",
        "age": 20
    },
            {
        "name": "allan",
        "age": 17
    },
     {
        "name": "julie",
        "age": 20
    },
     {
        "name": "jord",
        "age": 19
    }
```

List:

```
    { 
        "name": "jhenny",
        "age": 20,
        "color": "red"
        
    },
    {
        "name": "barry",
        "age": 20,
        "color": "black"
    },
     {
        "name": "julie",
        "age": 20,
        "color": "white"
    }
```

Result final List

```
    {
        "name": "barry",
        "age": 20,
        "color": "black"
    },
     {
        "name": "julie",
        "age": 20,
        "color": "white"
    }
```

Comment: can you show the compiler or actual error ?

Comment: the line erro: Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'java.lang,String', 'java.util.List<java.lang.String>'

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare a `String` with a `List<Grupo>`, but it seems you want to filter based on the response entity containing the grupoAd of the directio.

First collect the Strings from the List into a Set, then use `contains()` for the filter, somethingh  like this:

```
ResponseEntity<Gruoup> listaGrupo = monstarListaGrupo(login, token);
Set<String> names = listaGrupo.getBody().getGrupos().stream().collect(toSet());
List<Diretorio> diretorios = lista.stream()
    .filter(x -> names.contains(x.getGrupoAd()))
    ...
```

Comment: error map(java.util.function.Function<? super java.lang.String,? extends R>) in Stream cannor be applied to (<method reference>) reason no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that String conforms to Gruoup